# Regex to prevent trailing spaces and extra spaces

Tags: regex

Right now I have a regex that prevents the user from typing any special characters. The only allowed characters are A through Z, 0 through 9 or spaces.

I want to improve this regex to prevent the following:

1. No leading/training spaces - If the user types one or more spaces before or after the entry, do not allow.
2. No double-spaces - If the user types the space key more than once, do not allow.

The Regex I have right now to prevent special characters is as follows and appears to work just fine, which is:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$
```

Following some other ideas, I tried all these options but they did not work:

```
^\A\s+[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$\A\s+
/s*^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$/s*
```

Could I get a helping hand with this code? Again, I just want letters A-Z, numbers 0-9, and no leading or trailing spaces.

Thanks.

Comment: Like `^(?!.* {2})(?=\S.*\S$)[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$`? Is it C#?

Comment: What programming language?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?: [a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oL4nM9/3).

The regex will match alphanumerics at the start (1 or more) and then zero or more chunks of a single space followed with one or more alphanumerics.

As an alternative, here is a regex based on lookaheads (but is thus less efficient):

```
^(?!.* {2})(?=\S)(?=.*\S$)[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oL4nM9/4)

The `(?!.* {2})` disallows consecutive spaces and `(?=.*\S$)` requires a non-whitespace to be at the end of the string and `(?=\S)` requires it at the start.

Comment: Nice.  Though the alternative one doesn't catch valid 1-char strings.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you very much!

Comment: @wiktor-stribiżew I'm having an issue with trailing space in named capturing but couldn't make it working can you please guide me on what I'm missing? [Link to RegExp](https://regex101.com/r/WotpaP/1) The word "contact" must include in the match searchTerm that's what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @wiktor-stribiżew I also expected the last input (a single word) to match. Is it possible? [Expected Result](https://i.ibb.co/kMjDxYV/image.png)